# Is there any way to extract a list of users and their email ids from wattpad?

Tags: php, python

I've read the API documentation and there seem to be no way to get user email.

Comment: what else did you try?

Comment: enrich your question with links and references.

Answer (score 0):

if you can see a page witch contains your needed data with your eyes. you can use web scraping to gather them.